# How to install JDK1.7 on Mac

Tags: macos, mercurial, java, jdk1.7

I'm going to install the jdk1.7 on my macbook. But I cannot make it proper to be installed. 
I confronted an error which states that

> line 27: hg: command not found.

https://github.com/hgomez/obuildfactory/wiki/Building-and-Packaging-OpenJDK7-for-OSX

And I was following the above steps till I entered this code segment.

```
XBUILD=true ./obuildfactory/openjdk7/macosx/standalone-job.sh
```

I've fixed it by installing the official binary file instead of using brew verison. But I encountered another problem, which is as follows.

---

```
openjdkathome/sources/openjdk7/hotspot/src/share/vm/adlc/adlparse.cpp:4515:17: note: 
      use '=' to turn this equality comparison into an assignment
    if( (second == '=') ) {
                ^~
                =
5 errors generated.
make[8]: *** [../generated/adfiles/adlparse.o] Error 1
make[7]: *** [ad_stuff] Error 2
make[6]: *** [product] Error 2
make[5]: *** [generic_build2] Error 2
make[4]: *** [product] Error 2
make[3]: *** [all_product_universal] Error 2
make[2]: *** [universal_product] Error 2
make[1]: *** [hotspot-build] Error 2
make: *** [build_product_image] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`hg` is the Mercurial command line command - which the linked document says you should have installed from MacPorts or homebrew.

Comment: I have fixed it by install the official binary file instead of using brew. But I encounter another problem, which is shown as above.